# We Have the Power

Tags: knowledge, cipher

I was out supporting my local labor struggle when I got this request:

> 9F06 7F11 7F23
>   7F05 7F17
>   8F19 7G11 8F18 7G08 7G01 7F09 9F22 2F33 9F15
>   2F07 2F10 7F02

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should

> Play "Classical Gas"

It seems that the members of this cipher are

> The way in which episodes of *The Simpsons* are numbered

In particular

> 9F06 = **N**ew Kid on the Block
>  7F11 = **O**ne Fish, Two Fish, Blowfish, Blue Fish
>  7F23 = **W**hen Flanders Failed
>  7F05 = **D**ancin' Homer
>  7F17 = **O**ld Money
>  8F19 = **C**olonel Homer
>  7G11 = **L**ife on the Fast Lane
>  8F18 = **A** Streetcar Named Marge
>  7G08 = **S**impsons Roasting on an Open Fire
>  7G01 = **S**ome Enchanted Evening
>  7F09 = **I**tchy and Scratchy and Marge
>  9F22 = **C**ape Feare
>  2F33 = **A**nother Simpsons Clip Show
>  9F15 = **L**ast Exit to Springfield
>  2F07 = **G**rampa vs. Sexual Inadequacy
>  2F10 = **A**nd Maggie Makes Three
>  7F02 = **S**impson and Delilah

Reading out the first letters gives

> NOW DO CLASSICAL GAS

This is

> the request made by Lenny to Lisa during the episode "Last Exit to Springfield" and I think she does oblige.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mREi_Bb85Sk